# C# Exception with MySQL UPDATE query

Tags: c#, mysql, exception, error-handling

Recently, I have been working on a C# plugin for a game I play. My problem at the moment is that the query listed below is generating many errors, such as these errors:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Data too long for column 'lastServer' at row 1
>
> ^^This error shows when my lastServer data type is varchar(10), but when I changed it to varchar(25), it went away. However I would still like to know why this would be, if anyone is able to figure it out.

.

> My current error is having @lastServer, @characterName, and @ip showing up as @lastServer, @characterName, and @ip instead of their "AddWithValue" values.

Here's the query used for Table Creation:

```
                command.CommandText = string.Concat("CREATE TABLE `", MDiscipline.Instance.Configuration.Instance.PlayerInfoTableName, "` (`steamId` varchar(32) NOT NULL,`characterName` varchar(40) NOT NULL,`ip` varchar(15) NOT NULL, `lastPunishment` tinyint(2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,`lastServer` varchar(25) NOT NULL,`lastLogin` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp, PRIMARY KEY (`steamId`)) ");
```

And Here is the Code I'm having problems with:

```
        public void UpdatePlayerInfo(string steamid, string characterName, string ip)
    {
        try
        {
            MySqlConnection connection = createConnection();
            MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@steamId", steamid);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@characterName", characterName);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ip", ip);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastServer", MDiscipline.Instance.Configuration.Instance.Instance);
            command.CommandText = "UPDATE `" + MDiscipline.Instance.Configuration.Instance.PlayerInfoTableName + "` SET `characterName` = '@characterName', `ip` = '@ip', `lastServer` = '@lastServer', `lastLogin` = NOW() WHERE `steamId` = '" + steamid.ToString() + "';";
            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogException(ex);
        }
    }
```

> Helpful info to understand variables:

- MDiscipline.Instance.Configuration.Instance.PlayerInfoTableName can be translated to "player_info".
- steamid or (@steamId) can be translated to a 32 char number.
- characterName or (@characterName) can be translated to any value between 1 and 30 characters.
- ip or (@ip) can be translated to an ip address in a string, such as "255.255.255.255".
- MDiscipline.Instance.Configuration.Instance.Instance or (@lastServer) can be translated to Server01.

Comment: what is the size of lastServer column?

Comment: *SET `characterName` = '@characterName'`* you are telling it to save that as a literal.

Comment: When you say that i'm "telling it to save that as a literal", how would I correct this? Not very familiar with update queries, just the normal Insert, Delete, and Select ones.

Comment: Ster.Stack maybe @lastname is longer than 8 characters?

Comment: There is no `@lastname`, but I was able to fix `@lastServer` by changing the data type to varchar(25). Which I found interesting. However, i'm now having problems with @lastServer, `@characterName`, and `@ip` showing up as `@lastServer`, `@characterName`, and `@ip` in the MySQL table instead of their "AddWithValue" values.

Comment: the size of the lastServer column is varchar(10) from what I can see, "Server01" is only a varchar(8) value.

Comment: Can you run your code in debug mode and tell `MDiscipline.Instance.Configuration.Instance.Instance` value on  this line `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastServer", MDiscipline.Instance.Configuration.Instance.Instance);`